# How should a filter be created for a list of items in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a list of cars, like such: (simplified, of course)

```
<div class="car" data-image="true" data-specs="true">
   1. BMW
</div>
<div class="car" data-image="false" data-specs="true">
   2. Mercedes
</div>
<div class="car" data-image="true" data-specs="false">
   3. Audi
</div>
<div class="car" data-image="false" data-specs="false">
   4. Jaguar
</div>
```

What I want is a list of checkboxes that will filter the cars.

```
With image <input name="with_image" type="checkbox" />
With specs <input name="with_specs" type="checkbox" />
```

If both the checkboxes are ticked, I would like to have just the first car displayed and the others hidden.

The problem is that if I simply `hide()` and `show()` them when the checkbox is checked or unchecked, it will not know if the other checkbox is checked or not. For example, if I select both the checkboxes, only the first car will be shown, but when I uncheck the `with_specs` one, the forth car will be displayed as well, even though it does not have an image.

How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fully dynamic and can be extended any way by adding more cars or checkboxes :

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    var checks = $.map($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked'), function(el) {
        return el.name.replace('with_','');
    });

    $('.car').each(function(_,el) {
        var h = 0;
        for (var i=0; i<checks.length; i++) {
            if ( !!$(el).data(checks[i]) ) h++;
        }
        $(el).toggle(h===checks.length);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BA8px/1/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(':checkbox').change(function(){

  // hide all
  $('.car').hide();

  // show with image when image checkbox is checked
  if($('[name=with_image]').is(':checked'))
    $('[data-image=true]').show();

  // show with specs when specs checkbox is checked
  if($('[name=with_specs]').is(':checked'))
    $('[data-specs=true]').show();
})
```

Flickering could be disturbing, I would think in improving that.

Answer (score 2):

Bind a handler to the change event on the checkboxes, so that you can modify the visible cars each time a box is toggled. Then, hide all the cars and show the relevant ones which match the filter criteria.

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    $cars = $("div.car").hide();
    if (this.name == "with_image" && $(this).is(":checked")) {
        $cars.filter("[data-image='true']").show();
    }
    if (this.name == "with_specs" && $(this).is(":checked")) {
        $cars.filter("[data-specs='true']").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the same function each time you check a checkbox, that gets all the checked boxes and applies your filters.
Just give them a class.

```
$(".checkbox:checked").each(function(){
    //probably start with a helper function to show all
    //then hide the ones you want to hide.
});
```